# Asterisk Regex check if number entered has 10 digits

Tags: asterisk

I am using Asterisk 11, and I am new to it.

I have added the following to my extensions.conf file:

```
exten => 2, 1(start), Read(callBack,enter-phone-number10,10,,5)
 
exten => 2, n, GotoIf($[${REGEX("^\d{10}$" ${callBack})} = 1]?confirm)  -->not working, goes back to Start
   
exten => 2, n, GotoIf($[${REGEX("^\d{10}$" ${callBack})} != 1]?start) --> works, goes back to Start

exten => 2, n(confirm), Read(done,if-this-is-correct&press-1&otherwise&press-2)
```

I need to validate that the number entered has 10 digits.

If the user enters 10 digits, it's supposed to go to confirm, but it's going back to start. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like simpler for you use function LEN

If you want use regexp, you should use something like this, like it described in manuals:

```
exten => 2,n, GotoIf($[${REGEX("^[0-9]\{10\}$" ${callBack})}]?confirm:start)  -->not working, goes back to Start
```

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-func-regex/

Comment: LEN will let you enter numbers such as 123456789*, but I only want 10 digits. I cannot get your REGEX example to work, it always returns false.

Comment: Try use [0-9] instead of \d

Comment: There is also FILTER, so LEN(FILTER) will give you digits only.

Comment: Dont understand why. Because ```Read()``` ends with 10 digits as seen in your example. No check necessary.

Comment: Read will read UPTO 10 digits, for example, can be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Check code below

```
exten => 2, 1(start), Read(callBack,enter-phone-number10,10,,5)
exten => 2, n, GoToIf($[LEN(${callBack}) = 10]?confirm:start)
```